# SharePoint 2010 Error adding a Feature Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature-activation, feature-receiver

I want to add a Feature event receiver, that add a webpart to a page, 
I followed the steps in this [link](http://sptechbytes.blogspot.ch/2014/10/sharepoint-2013-programmatically-adding_18.html)

But when I tried to deploy it , I hade the following error :

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Assemblies that
>   implement ASP.NET Web Parts and are installed into a partially trusted
>   location, such as the bin directory, must be compiled with the
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute set for import to succeed.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: try deploying through powershell once, and see if it also throws same error, probably it should not

Comment: @Gaurravs , I found the  FIX:
Add the following to your AssemblyInfo.cs and recompile.usingSystem.Runtime.InteropServices;[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] . Thanks for you help ..

Comment: good. you can put it as answer. so someone seeking same will be helped

Comment: You will see `Answer Your Question` button below

Answer (score 0):

FIX :

Add the following to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` and `recompile.usingSystem.Runtime.InteropServices;[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] .`